# 'EM_Colorswatches_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, magento

kindly Help me i am working in magento after install extension when i go system--conf this error show 'EM_Colorswatches_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: i already have try 6 swatch extension for color and size every extension send me error in same condition

Answer (score 1):

check file in your magento root:
/app/code/local/EM/Colorswatches/Helper/Data.php or  /app/code/community/EM/Colorswatches/Helper/Data.php

Looks like you removed this extension or some files but have some templates still use that.

But if you looking for color swatches extension the best way is use ConfigurableSwatches from Magento Core that works fine.

ConfigurableSwatches extension has been available since version 1.9 for RWD Theme. if your theme based on Default or another theme, so you need copy templates, js and css files from rwd theme, related to this extesion, to your theme.

Comment: he should also check app/etc/modules/EM_Colorswatches.xml to make sure the module is active and also to see if it is point at the local or community directory.

Comment: in this root have fie /app/code/community/EM/Colorswatches/Helper/Data.php

Comment: check app/etc/modules/EM_Colorswatches.xml contains `<active>true</active>`